# insert into from one table to another with select (android sqlite)

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have two tables with exactly the same columns, except that the 2nd one has some additional ones.

I want to copy all of the data, except for the _id column from the 1st table into the 2nd. The names of the columns are exactly the same in both tables.

Here's the first table

```
private static final String TABLE_EXPENSES_CREATE = "create table " + TABLE_EXPENSES + " (" +
      COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
      COLUMN_DATE + " integer not null, " +
      COLUMN_AMOUNT + " real not null, " +
      COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text, " +
      COLUMN_REPEAT_ID + " integer," +
      " FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_REPEAT_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
      TABLE_REPEAT_METADATA + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")" +
      ");";
```

and the 2nd one

```
 private static final String TABLE_TRANSACTIONS_CREATE =
      "create table " + TABLE_TRANSACTIONS + " (" +
          COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
          COLUMN_DATE + " integer not null, " +
          COLUMN_AMOUNT + " real not null, " +
          COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " text, " +
          COLUMN_TYPE + " text not null, " +
          COLUMN_REPEAT_ID + " integer," +
          " FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_REPEAT_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
          TABLE_REPEAT_METADATA + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ")" +
          ");";
```

I'm trying to copy everything from the 1st table (except the COLUMN_ID) to the 2nd with following code:

```
db.rawQuery("insert into "
          + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_TRANSACTIONS
          + " ("
          + COLUMN_DATE
          + ", "
          + COLUMN_AMOUNT
          + ", "
          + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION
          + ", "
          + COLUMN_REPEAT_ID
          + ") select "
          + COLUMN_DATE
          + ", "
          + COLUMN_AMOUNT
          + ", "
          + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION
          + ", "
          + COLUMN_REPEAT_ID
          + " from "
          + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_EXPENSES, null);
```

However, there is no effect once the code runs. The logs don't show any errors. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`rawQuery`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) when you suppose some data to be returned (in `Cursor`).
For other purposes consider using [`execSQL`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)
In your case if you replace `db.rawQuery("insert into "...` with `db.execSQL("insert into " ...` it will work!

**P.S.** For `rawQuery` you can also read an interesting thing:
"The SQL string must not be ; terminated".
I got a lot of headache on it days ago ;)

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you.